# In Mario Kart Wii, can you download any Ghost data? -- the ones with no-glitch run

Tags: mario-kart-wii

If downloading the Top World Records or Regional records, some runs such as the Wario's Gold Mine or the Mushroom Gorge are using the glitch to do it, in 35 seconds or less.

Can you download the "no-glitch" versions?   Those videos are available on YouTube as "Wario Gold Mine no-glitch" but I'd like to download the Ghost data as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do that.  You can download your friend's ghosts, the top ghost (which is usually glitched) and a random ghost that is faster than you (your rival ghost).  Personally, I find the rival ghosts work really well to train yourself on a specific track, as you can learn and practice the "tricks of the track" one at a time.